# fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC only returning one row

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, pdo

Changing over from what is now depreciated mysql code, over to PDO.  This code is supposed to output all the values within the table. Here is the code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_id = :user_id');
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

and the code that calls the fields are:

```
$data_t .= '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
$data_t .= '<td>' . $row['length'] . '' . $selected . '</td>';
$data_t .= '<td>' . $row['ground'] . '' . $selected . '</td>';
```

For some reason, rather than output all of the matching values selected, only one is spit out.  Now I also make use of a count function to display how many entries a person has made, and that shows one entry less than is actually in the database. (meaning it displays a numerical count of 4 if 5 exist)  Here is that code:

```
$rResult = $stmt->fetchAll();
$gorResult = count($rResult);
```

I have tried using fetchAll() with this code and that returns nothing at all.  I know I must be missing something here, and it's likely simple for someone with a fresh brain.  Again the issue is this call only outputs one row, rather than all matching rows.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_id = :user_id');
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userid);
$stmt->execute();

$rResult = $stmt->fetchAll();
$gorResult = count($rResult);

foreach($rResult as $row) {


$data_t = '<b>Length: '. $strt_length .' </b>  |  <b>Ground: '. $strt_ground .' </b>';
$data_t .= '<span class="label label-success">'. $gorResult .' Entries Total</span>';
$data_t .= '<table class="table table-striped">';
$data_t .= '<thead>';
$data_t .= '<tr>';
$data_t .= '<th>' . $table_fields['jo_col_1_name'] . '</th>'; 
$data_t .= '<th>' . $table_fields['jo_col_2_name'] . '</th>'; 
$data_t .= '<th>' . $table_fields['jo_col_3_name'] . '</th>';
$data_t .= '</tr>';
$data_t .= '</thead>';
$data_t .= '<tbody>';
$data_t .= '<tr>';
$data_t .= '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
$data_t .= '<td>' . $row['length'] . '' . $selected . '</td>';
$data_t .= '<td>' . $row['ground'] . '' . $selected . '</td>';
$data_t .= '<td>';

if (!$del_hide) {

$data_t .= "<form method='post' action='');' />";
$data_t .= "<input type='hidden' name='primary_key' value='".$row["primary_key"]."' />";
$data_t .= '<button type="submit" name="deleteItem" value="delete" class="btn btn-link">';
$data_t .= '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>';
} else { };
$data_t .= '<button type="image" name="image" value="image" class="btn btn-link">';
$data_t .= '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></button>';
$data_t .= '</form>';
}
$data_t .= '</td>';
$data_t .= '<td>';
$data_t .= '</td>';
$data_t .= '</tr>';
$data_t .= '</tbody>';
$data_t .= '</table>';

echo $data_t;
?>
```

Comment: `$data_t = '<b>Length: '...` is a problem row

Comment: Why all that `$data_t .= ` mess anyway? Any reason you are using it? Are you aware of this PHP feature: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Why is this a WordPress question? WordPress has an [API for db queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_API). Or are you using some other data source as well?

Comment: fetchAll doesnt go with WHILE but with FOREACH beacuse fetchall returns the whole set and while goes rows by row so it sees the resultset as a single row.

Comment: Also how many rows are in that table with the corresponding userid?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your long and windy story, you are doing something like this

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // fetching one row
    $data_t .= '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>'; // using row
    $rResult = $stmt->fetchAll(); // FETCHING REST OF ROWS
    ...
} // no more rows for the next iteration
```

while it have to be

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(); // fetching rows
$count = count($data); // getting count
foreach($data as $row) { // iterating over rows
    $data_t .= '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>'; // using row
}
```

Comment: While your code did properly display the correct row count, it still only displays one row from the table.  So the same issue remains.

Comment: Well, it's something with the way *you* output your data then.

Comment: I uploaded my exact code in the order I am using it.  Would you take a look please?  I seriously am ready to bang my head against my desk here.

Comment: Try to simplify it. Start from `var_dump($data);`. This way you will be assured that array indeed contains **exactly the very same number of items** as count() says. Then turn to your HTML output code. And debug it. Honestly, it has nothing to do with PDO in the first place, and - secondly - making your code work is your job.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one row because you specified `user_id` (which, I assume, is unique key). Just remove it.

Comment: Well I have a separate database which stores multiple rows for each userID and each has a cell with the userID in it for identification.  So that is not the issue.  Thank you for your input though!

Comment: This should not be downvoted at all, though it did not answer the question, it is still helpful. @ElonThan did not know the structure of the database, naturally seeing an ID in a where clause would lead almost anyone to believe that you are limiting your search to one record. This is a valid answer.